# C in Linux - using execle() to output an environment variable?

Tags: c, linux

**Program 1**

In program 1 I have attempted to create the sole environment variable envar putting it in the env array which is passed to the execle function for the environments creation which program 2 will be run in.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int ret;
char envar[] = "Big ol' environment variable ;D"; 
char *env[2] = {envar, 0};

ret = execle("./exec_test1.1", "exec_test1.1", 0, env);

printf("my prog failed ret = %d", ret);

return 0;
}
```

**Program 2**

I intended this code in the same directory to retrieve the environment variable envar on execution and to print it. However I the output in its place is null "memes and dis (null)" I have searched but can't see my mistake. Program two is almost identical to another I found for the same purpose so I assume my mistake is in program one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

char *envptr = getenv("envar");

printf("memes and dis %s\n", envptr);

return 0;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try with `putenv("NAME=value");` and `system()` instead of execle. See man pages for putenv and system. `execle()` replace you running program with anoter.

Comment: @ulix: no I wouldn't recommend this - this way you are setting `program1`'s environment variable and not only `program2`s, which is probably not what you want. Also using `system` uses the shell, so it may be less secure. In summary, it's a bad hack, not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong `envar` variable format - it must be `NAME=VALUE`. So fixing program 1 to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret;
    char envar[] = "envar=Big ol' environment variable ;D"; 
    char *env[2] = {envar, 0};

    ret = execle("./exec_test1.1", "exec_test1.1", 0, env);
    printf("my prog failed ret = %d", ret);

    return 0;
}
```

should make it work.

(I also took some liberty and formatted the code to make it more readable)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The example I was going off does some wild stuff assigning shellcode to the environment variable which is why I got confused.

Comment: You're welcome. Also don't forget that C-variable name has meaning just in C code - naming the C-variable `envar` may have been what confused you - you probably assumed you already have name assigned.